# Rijndael 256 Encrypt/decrypt between C# and PHP 7.2+

Tags: c#, php, encryption, mcrypt, php-openssl

I have already implemented Rijandael 256 encryption on C# side which looks like this:

```
public static string EncryptPasswordForWordpressPlugin(string message)
{
    const string Ivstring = "W4jlzx2XaqQTtbd67813xys4133tl2S7";
    string keystring = "I7R9VdkzGQ215iCkC0940ST01Wk58Mr9";

    byte[] key = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keystring);
    byte[] iv = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Ivstring);

    string encrypted = null;
    var rj = new RijndaelManaged {BlockSize = 256};
    rj.Key = key;
    rj.IV = iv;
    rj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    try
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rj.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
            {
                sw.Write(message);
                sw.Close();
            }
            cs.Close();
        }
        byte[] encoded = ms.ToArray();
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);

        ms.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        rj.Clear();
    }

    return encrypted;
}
```

And in PHP I had decryption implementation with mcrypt:

```
class Decrypt {

    protected $mcrypt_cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
    protected $mcrypt_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
    protected $key = "I7R9VdkzGQ215iCkC0940ST01Wk58Mr9";
    protected $iv = "W4jlzx2XaqQTtbd67813xys4133tl2S7";

    public function decrypt($encrypted){
        $iv_utf = mb_convert_encoding($this->iv, 'UTF-8');
        return mcrypt_decrypt($this->mcrypt_cipher, $this->key, base64_decode($encrypted), $this->mcrypt_mode, $iv_utf);

    }
}
```

Now with PHP 7.2 `mcrypt` is removed and I am looking for a way to implement decryption in PHP without changing C# side.

I am not really good with encryption/decryption and was not able to find properly solution. 
Is it possible to implement this decryption using `openssl` in PHP or is there another way. 
Thank you.

Comment: Well, You use block size 256. That is not AES. I don't think that new libraries are going to port non-standard Rijandael. If Possible switch to AES.

Comment: Note that the large block size does offer some protection in the stated protocol. You should not use a static IV like that, because it exposes identical initial blocks. With a 256 bit / 32 byte block size this won't be so much of a problem because any difference in the passwords will encrypt to a different ciphertext. Use a random IV and a real key for the next protocol.